# How to install window trim with uneven surrounding materials?

Tags: windows, trim

We are installing basement windows.  The concrete wall has a ledge that the bricks siding sits on.  The bricks are inset by at least a 1/2" from the outer face of the concrete.  There are lintels holding up the bricks which protrude about 1/4" past the brick, so still 1/4" shy of being flush with the concrete.  I will need make up the difference somehow to get the trim on flat.  Any ideas?  (in attached sketch windows aren't installed)

Also, what do I use for drip edge?  It'd go either above the lintel or behind trim? (Lintel isn't installed yet & is 3" deep)
Thanks

[image: Sketch of window opening]

Just to clarify, we are using precast concrete lintels.  (This is not our project but shows what it is)  BUT our window won't be recessed.

[image]